# SQLException: Transaction BEGIN / COMMIT mismatch

Tags: transactions, sqlexception

I have seen the posts and tried to solve this problem but not able to. So here is the code. Help to solve the same.

I have one procedure which calls another procedure.

Caller Procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[DadSaveMembership]
@PERSON AS [dbo].[Person_Master_Type] Readonly,
@ADDRESS AS [dbo].[Address_Master_Type] Readonly, 
@MEMBERSHIP AS [dbo].[Membership_Type] Readonly

AS
BEGIN

declare @pid int, @aid int, @CUR_PID int, @CUR_ADD int, @atype int, @created_by int
declare @created_date date

select @pid=person_id from @PERSON
select @aid=address_id from @ADDRESS

if(@pid=0)
begin
    INSERT INTO PERSON_MASTER (TITLE,FNAME,MNAME,LNAME,DOB,GENDER,MARITALSTATUS,MOBILE,EMAIL,CREATED_BY,CREATED_DATE)
    SELECT TITLE,FNAME,MNAME,LNAME,DOB,GENDER,MARITALSTATUS,MOBILE,EMAIL,CREATED_BY,CREATED_DATE FROM @PERSON
    SELECT @CUR_PID=MAX(PERSON_ID) FROM PERSON_MASTER
end
else
begin
    set @CUR_PID=@pid
end

if(@aid=0)
begin
    INSERT INTO ADDRESS_MASTER (ADDRESS1,ADDRESS2,ADDRESS3,CITY_ID,PINCODE,PHONE,CREATED_BY,CREATED_DATE)
    SELECT ADDRESS1,ADDRESS2,ADDRESS3,CITY_ID,PINCODE,PHONE,CREATED_BY,CREATED_DATE FROM @ADDRESS
    SELECT @CUR_ADD=MAX(ADDRESS_ID) FROM ADDRESS_MASTER
end
else
begin
    set @CUR_ADD=@aid
end



EXEC [dbo].[GET_DAD_COUNT_AID$IMPL$AUTO] @CUR_PID, "3", @CUR_ADD, @atype OUTPUT

INSERT INTO PERSON_MODULE_LINK (PERSON_ID,MODULE_ID,ADDRESS_ID,ADDRESS_TYPE,CREATED_BY,CREATED_DATE) 
VALUES (@CUR_PID,3,@CUR_ADD,@atype,@CREATED_BY,@CREATED_DATE)

END
```

Another procedure is as follows

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GET_DAD_COUNT_AID$IMPL$AUTO]  
@pid int,
@modid int,
@addrid int,
@return_value_argument int  OUTPUT
AS 

BEGIN

  SET  IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS  ON

  DECLARE
     @cnt int, 
     @cnt1 int


  SELECT @cnt1 = isnull(max(CAST(ADDRESS_HISTORY_DETAIL.ADDRESS_TYPE AS numeric(38, 10))), 0)
  FROM dbo.ADDRESS_HISTORY_DETAIL
  WHERE 
     ADDRESS_HISTORY_DETAIL.PERSON_ID = @pid AND 
     ADDRESS_HISTORY_DETAIL.MODULE_ID = @modid AND 
     ADDRESS_HISTORY_DETAIL.ADDRESS_ID = @addrid



  SELECT @cnt = isnull(max(CAST(PERSON_MODULE_LINK.ADDRESS_TYPE AS numeric(38, 10))), 0)
  FROM dbo.PERSON_MODULE_LINK
  WHERE 
     PERSON_MODULE_LINK.PERSON_ID = @pid AND 
     PERSON_MODULE_LINK.MODULE_ID = @modid AND 
     PERSON_MODULE_LINK.ADDRESS_ID = @addrid



  IF @cnt1 > @cnt
     BEGIN

        SET @return_value_argument = @cnt1+1

        RETURN 

     END
  ELSE 
     BEGIN

        SET @return_value_argument = @cnt+1

        RETURN 

     END

END
```

the problem is I am getting following error when DadSaveMembership SP is called:
Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding. So, what is wrong?

Comment: What is the actual problem? You've posted two queries without stating what the problem is.

Comment: edit my question to tell actual problem

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the problem is the `SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS ON` command in the **GET_DAD_COUNT_AID$IMPL$AUTO** stored procedure. Reading [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187807.aspx) it would appear that by setting the command and executing a SELECT command a transaction is created but never committed or rolled back. You can either wrap the original SP in a transaction BEGIN `TRANSACTION` + `COMMIT` / `ROLLBACK` or remove the statement all together.

You should also consider replacing these two statements:

```
SELECT @CUR_ADD=MAX(ADDRESS_ID) FROM ADDRESS_MASTER
SELECT @CUR_PID=MAX(PERSON_ID) FROM PERSON_MASTER
```

with these:

```
SELECT @CUR_ADD = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
SELECT @CUR_PID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```